# How to convert XML schema to Relational schema in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I saw the following solution in this [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConvertXMLDataIntoRelationalTableDataUsingTeiid?_sscc=t)

```
select * from xmltable('/dept/employee' PASSING convert('<dept bldg="101">
    <employee id="901">
        <name>
            <first>John</first>
            <last>Doe</last>
        </name>
        <office>344</office>
        <salary currency="USD">55000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee id="902">
        <name>
            <first>Peter</first>
            <last>Pan</last>
        </name>
        <office>216</office>
        <phone>905-416-5004</phone>
    </employee>
</dept>', xml) COLUMNS 
   empID     integer     PATH '@id',
   firstname     string     PATH 'name/first',
   lastname     string     PATH 'name/last') AS employee
```

That's exactly the solution that I am looking for, **but** in C# !

Is it possible? Any suggestion or references would be of help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear how this mapping from XML to tables would cope with repeating elements, e.g. multiple phone numbers.

Comment: Not sure how, but the "Path" resulting in multiple rows should duplicate the value of other columns.